# Trying to calculate Celsius into Fahrenheit in reactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to convert celsius into fahrenheit inside the div. I am new to React so it is quite confusing where to put the converting calculation.

```
return (
    <div className="app">
        <main>
            <div className="search-box">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-bar"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
                    value={query}
                    onKeyPress={search}
                />
            </div>
            {(typeof weather.main != "undefined") ? (<div>
                <div className='location-box'>
                    <div className='location'>{weather.name}, {weather.sys.country}</div> <div className='date'>{dateBuilder(new Date())}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="weather-box">
                    <div className="celsius-temp">{Math.round(weather.main.temp)}°C </div>
                    <div className="fahrenheit-temp">{Math.round(weather.main.temp)}°F </div>
                    <div className="weather">{weather.weather[0].main} </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ) : ('')}
        </main>
    </div>
)
```

I want to print out two values of temperatures, one celsius (from the weather API) and another one fahrenheit (converted it from the celsius value).

I tried doing ({Math.round(weather.main.temp)} * 9/5) + 32 inside the  but it did not work. (as seen in the image)
Should I try making a const value inside the function on top, inside the function App().

Please help.

Comment: Please check out [ask] including the section about including code as text and not as an image

Answer (score 2):

The entire equation needs to be inside the curly braces {}. Only code inside the curly braces will be run; anything outside them will be displayed as-is.

Instead of:

```
<div className="celsius-temp">({Math.round(weather.main.temp)} * 9/5) + 32</div>
```

Try this:

```
<div className="celsius-temp">{(Math.round(weather.main.temp) * 9/5) + 32}</div>
```